# missing Java library Mac osx AIR Developer Tool

Tags: java, build, air, adt, ipa

I'm hoping someone can help or has experienced a similar problem with using Adobe AIR for development and packaging of iOS apps. I'm currently trying to build my as3 source code into an ipa to install onto my test device but unfortunately I'm having a re-occurring error returned from java:

```
ios-debug-package: /** adt_jar -package -target ipa-test-interpreter-simulator **/
     [java] ld: library not found for -lgcc_s.1
     [java] Compilation failed while executing : ld64

BUILD FAILED
build.xml:372: Java returned: 12
```

that I can't seem to find any information on this missing java library. I can run the app on the same Mac through the ADL by compiling the as3 code using mxmlc with no issues. As far as I know xcode, the AIR sdk, my certificates and provisions are all set up correctly but I'm starting to run out of ideas here.

Couple of details on the system:

MaxBook 13" late 2006 running Mac OS X 10.7.5

AIR sdk version 3.5 with flex 4.6

using ANT 1.9 to for building

xCode 4.6.1

Java latest update for the OS found at this link: support.apple.com/kb/dl1421

thanks in advance!

Comment: getting the same error, have you had any luck figuring this out?